# VS Code: Local source code with remote run/debug

Tags: visual-studio-code, remote-debugging

I have my personal machine, which has version control credentials, VS code, etc. all set up as I like it.

I have a remote machine that has some specialized hardware that my code uses. I don't want to set it up as a development environment through, as it's a shared machine/account and I don't want my version control credentials and such stored on that machine.

I'd like to be able to set it up such that the source code is on my personal machine, but when I run/debug in VS Code, it sends the executable to the remote machine and runs it there (and Delve connects to a port on that machine so I can step through from my local machine).

Is this possible with VS Code? I know it supports [Remote Development](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/remote/remote-overview), but that's just where your local VS Code connects to a remote VS Code server, and the source code is on the remote machine.

Comment: I don't know if there's a specific extension for this, but you could set up a script to copy the executable from your PC to the shared PC, then run it? Maybe you could make a task in VS Code to do this

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you're talking about some native binary code in C or C++,
you probably want to have a look at debugging over a piped transport:
https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/cpp/pipe-transport to be used as part of your debugging setup, for instance for c++: https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/cpp/launch-json-reference

Note you will still need gdb and the debug symbols on the remote machine.